# Is creating/modifying with Cypher possible in Memgraph?

Tags: cypher, graph-databases, memgraphdb

I'm trying to explore Memgraph a bit since I love Cypher. The website mentions querying with Cypher, but I'm wondering whether creating/modifying with Cypher is also possible.
The website also mentions a bunch of other cool features, which I may end up also using (Kafka streaming straight into the store seems very cool)
It pretty much boils down to

- Is Memgraph a persistent store?
- Can I also just use Cypher to create/modify nodes?
- The website seems to put great emphasis on the whole real-time aspect, can you explain a bit about what that means?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, Memgraph is a persistent store for graph data. It uses two mechanisms to ensure the durability of the stored data: write-ahead logging (WAL) and
taking periodic snapshots. You can read more about storage in our docs at
https://memgraph.com/docs/memgraph/concepts/storage .

Memgraph uses the Cypher query language, so you can use it like you’ve used it in Neo4j, with a couple of differences mentioned here:
https://memgraph.com/docs/cypher-manual/differences

In our documentation, you can also find the whole Cypher manual with examples of how to use it with Memgraph.

When it comes to streaming, Memgraph along with Kafka allows you to stream your data and analyze it in real-time.